# jQuery update data attributes using Json syntax

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to update only one option in data array:

```
<a class="status" data-set='{"field": "status", "id": 2, "result": "3"}'>Click</a>
```

I need **result** to be updated from 3 to lets say 4.

Here  is my code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.status', function() {
    var data = $(this).data("set");
    value = data.result == 3 ? 4 : 3;
    $(this).data("set", {"val":value});


    console.log(data)

});
```

On click replaces the whole data-set attribute with [object, object]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably giving you the data as a string try:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.status', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data("set");
    data.result = data.result == 3 ? 4 : 3;
    $this.data("set", JSON.stringify(data));


    console.log(data)

});
```

Comment: No, I'm getting correct object. Your solution gives error:        SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
 

var data = JSON.parse($this.data("set"));

Comment: I updated the response. If it doesn't need to be manually parsed then you should be able to do it this way.

Comment: Replacing the last line with: $this.attr("data-set", JSON.stringify(data));  works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manipulate objects in data attributes directly as follows:

```
$(this).data('set').result = 4;
//or $(this).data()['set']['result'] = 4;
//or $(this).data().set.result = 4;
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('a.status').on('click', function() {
  $(this).data('set').result = $(this).data('set').result == 3 ? 4 : 3;
  console.log( $(this).data('set') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="status" data-set='{"field": "status", "id": 2, "result": "3"}'>Click</a>
```